# Warp.js help Javascript Change Time Speed

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where it is important that I can manipulate time speed. This JS module:

https://github.com/mattbradley/warpjs/blob/master/README.md

seems to be exactly what I need, but I don't think I'm trying to use it right. I can't get the .speed([]); to change the time rate. Here is my example:

```
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>

    <body>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="warp.js"></script>


        <div id="container"></div>
        <span id="info"></span><br>
        <span id="time"></span>
        <span id="time2"></span>

        <script>


      setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date;
        now = Date.warp.clock(true);
        //now = Date.warp.speed([1]); // DOESNT WORK?

        var dateD = [now.getMonth() + 1,now.getDate(),now.getFullYear()];
        var dateE = [now.getHours(),now.getMinutes(),now.getSeconds()];
        var MDY = dateD.join("/");
        var HMS = dateE.join(":");
        time.innerHTML = (MDY);
        time2.innerHTML = (HMS);

      }, 20);


        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Date.warp.speed(1);` will work, the brackets in the function documentation mean it is an optional parameter. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/mattbradley/warpjs/blob/master/warp.js) on line 131 the speed method sets `tickSpeed` which is an integer

Comment: It's not incorrect documentation, `Date.warp.speed([speed])` just indicates that `speed` is an optional parameter. It may be a bit unclear if it's new to you, I agree, but it's a common convetion for documenting optional parameters in functions.

Comment: I tried Date.warp.speed(1). It doesn't work... it crashes something and the clock disappears.